# How to disable custom icons for program in XFCE

Tags: linux, xfce, theme, icons

I use many File manager (for some reasons) but they all have the same icon (besides Nemo), making it hard to recognize.

Is there a way to disable this so that every File mnager use it's own original icon?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon can be changed in the launcher file.

The launcher file can be found in `/usr/share/applications`. For example, PCManFM has launcher file `pcmanfm.desktop`, Thunar has `Thunar.desktop` and so on.

- Open the corresponding `.desktop` file, then
- Look for the line `Icon=FOO` and change the icon name `FOO` to other icon name of choice.

The icon name can be any icon name found in `/usr/share/icons` directory. User may install an alternative icon theme that has folder icons with multiple colours.

Some alternative icon themes:

- [Oxygen icon theme](https://github.com/KDE/oxygen-icons) (`oxygen-icon-theme` for all Debian, Ubuntu)
- [Papirus icon theme](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme) (`papirus-icon-theme` for Debian 10+, Ubuntu 18.04+)

There is no "own original icons" for most file managers, so use different colours of folder instead.

Comment: thanks but, I don't want change icons manually and am not a big fan icon themes changing default programs icons. Even if they are "more beautiful"

Comment: So from my understanding, the fact that lot of file managers have the same icon is an specification/recommendation ?

Comment: At this point, am not sure what "desktop environment" really means but, does all this mean they expect you, to use/install only one file manager in your linux system? Like if I chose XFCE and have Thuanar pre-installed, they don't expect me to install Nautilus or Dolphin?

Comment: Xfce is one desktop environment (DE). Each DE has one file managers by default: Xfce - Thunar; GNOME - Nautilus; KDE - Dolphin; Cinnamon - Nemo; LXDE/LXQt - PCManFM, etc. User has choice to install one or more file managers, but sometimes that will break user experience (too much to explain here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87379/discussion-between-asme-just-and-clearkimura).